# Firebase SMTP settings Message not delivered

Tags: reactjs, email, firebase-authentication, smtp

Using Firebase for my application, the Email Address Verification and Password Reset isn't working. I keep getting the below error. I cant figure out what SMTP settings I should be using. I have used both hotmail and gmail and neither are working. any help is much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your error message, code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)